# node-gyp rebuild fail on m1 while installing dependencies

Tags: npm, node-modules, node-gyp, yarn-v2

I'm trying to install the project dependency,
and it's failing on trying to rebuild node-gyp, when I removed 'metrohash' from the project dependency everything is working perfectly,
but I can't because it's a shared project,
and it's working for other developers (with Intel chip macbooks)

I've tried:

1. reinstall xcode
2. reinstall python2
3. update brew
4. uninstall 'metrohash' and 'yarn' to all other dependencies and reinstall 'metrohash'
5. remove node_modules, dist and reinstall
6. install node-sass globally

I'm using m1 pro macbook pro with Monterey 12.5.1

```
# This file contains the result of Yarn building a package (metrohash@npm:2.8.0.**.tgz)
# Script code: node-gyp rebuild

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
gyp info using node@14.20.0 | darwin | arm64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.6 found at "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/bin/python3"
gyp info spawn /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/user/Projects/project-name/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/user/Projects/project-name/node_modules/metrohash/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/user/Projects/project-name/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/user/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.20.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/user/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.20.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/user/Projects/project-name/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/user/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.20.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/user/Projects/project-name/node_modules/metrohash',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/metrohash/src/metrohash_wrapper.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-msse4.2' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/metrohash/src/metrohash128.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-msse4.2' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/metrohash/src/metrohash128crc.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-msse4.2' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
In file included from ../src/metrohash128crc.cpp:27:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/nmmintrin.h:14:2: error: "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
#error "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
 ^
In file included from ../src/metrohash128crc.cpp:27:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/nmmintrin.h:19:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/smmintrin.h:14:2: error: "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
#error "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
 ^
In file included from ../src/metrohash128crc.cpp:27:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/nmmintrin.h:19:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/smmintrin.h:17:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/tmmintrin.h:14:2: error: "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
#error "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
 ^
In file included from ../src/metrohash128crc.cpp:27:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/nmmintrin.h:19:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/smmintrin.h:17:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/tmmintrin.h:17:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/pmmintrin.h:14:2: error: "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
#error "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
 ^
In file included from ../src/metrohash128crc.cpp:27:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/nmmintrin.h:19:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/smmintrin.h:17:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/tmmintrin.h:17:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/pmmintrin.h:17:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/emmintrin.h:14:2: error: "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
#error "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
 ^
In file included from ../src/metrohash128crc.cpp:27:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/nmmintrin.h:19:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/smmintrin.h:17:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/tmmintrin.h:17:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/pmmintrin.h:17:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/emmintrin.h:17:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:14:2: error: "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
#error "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
 ^
In file included from ../src/metrohash128crc.cpp:27:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/nmmintrin.h:19:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/smmintrin.h:17:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/tmmintrin.h:17:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/pmmintrin.h:17:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/emmintrin.h:17:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:17:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:14:2: error: "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
#error "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:37:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_emms'; did you mean '__builtin_isless'?
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:37:5: note: '__builtin_isless' declared here
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:37:25: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 0
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:54:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:71:12: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si'
    return __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si((__v2si)__m, 0);
           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:133:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packsswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:163:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packssdw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:193:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packuswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:220:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:243:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:264:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:291:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:314:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/metrohash/src/metrohash128crc.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/user/Projects/project-name/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:203:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:285:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/bin/node" "/Users/user/Projects/project-name/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/user/Projects/project-name/node_modules/metrohash
gyp ERR! node -v v14.20.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: noer is this resolved if yes can you please share the solution. Thanks